# Facebook Graph API - Account spending limit

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I work with facebook graph API and would like to download Account spending limit. I am using in explorer query - act_account_ID/insights?fields=spend&level=account - to extract spend value, but still have missing limit. Any idea how to download this value?
Regards,
K

[Manager account screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbvAp.png)

Comment: Isn’t that just the `spend_cap` field of the ad account object …? _“The total amount that this account can spend, after which all campaigns will be paused, based on amount_spent.”_

Comment: You are right, Thank you :) I am using fb API not so long, and as far used only in format act_account_ID/insights?fields=..;act_account_ID/campaigns?fields=.. and here it was enough to use act_account_ID/?fields=spend_cap. Once more thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the `spend_cap` field of the ad account object:

> The total amount that this account can spend, after which all campaigns will be paused, based on amount_spent. A value of 0 signifies no spending-cap and setting a new spend cap only applies to spend AFTER the time at which you set it.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-account